# Pb with angular $interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone explain me what append in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/f5x8dddMMgQDT2qCsjl8?p=preview)

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.name = 'World';


  var plop = $interval(function(){}, 1000);

  $scope.test = function(){
    console.log("test");
  }

})
```

---

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">  
  <p ng-class="test()">Hello {{name}}!</p>
</body>
```

If you open the console, you can see "test" is outputting repeatedly but it's not in the $interval function !!!

Comment: try to refresh you plunkr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ng-class` is an attribute that is evaluated on every `$digest` loop. Since the `<p>` element's `ng-class` is a function call to `test()`, `test()` will be evaluated on `$digest`.

`$interval` is a wrapper for `setInterval` bound to angular's digest loop, so it is essentially saying "run the digest loop once per second". When the digest loop runs, `test()` is evaluated again, which causes the console message to be printed once more.